# Non-Measurable set construction on a unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am wondering about part 3 of the following question. I was hoping to get another hint. Thank you.

Identify the interval $[0,1]$ with the unit circle $S^1=\{e^{i\theta}:\theta\in[0,2\pi)\}\subset\mathbb C$. 
We will construct a set in $S^1$ that is not Borel-measurable.  To this end, for $z=e^{i\alpha},w=e^{i\beta}\in S^1$, we say $z\sim w$ if $\alpha-\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$. This is clearly an equivalence relation. 
Using the axiom of choice we can construct a set $\Lambda$ whose elements are one from each equivalence class. For $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ let $\Lambda_\alpha=e^{i\alpha}\Lambda$ be the rotation of $\Lambda$ by the angle $\alpha$.

1) Prove that if $\alpha,\beta\in[0,2\pi)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ are distinct, then $\Lambda_\alpha\cap\Lambda_\beta=\varnothing$.

2) Prove that $S^1$ is the union over $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ of $\Lambda_\alpha$.

3) Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $S^1$ (equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). Prove that $m(\Lambda)$ cannot exist. (Hint: use the thing you just proved and the fact that $m$ is shift-invariant.)

Some quick notes on the problem:

A relation of equivalence breaks the entire circle into disjoint equivalence classes. In this problem, we have countable many equivalence classes (ie. one from each rational number). In other words, to get an equivalence class, we pick one element from each class. To get an equivalence class, I pick an element, say $\gamma$ from $\Lambda$ and then we have $\{\gamma+\alpha: \alpha \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is the set of all elements equivalent to $\gamma$.

Comment: Hint: if it exists, $m(\Lambda)$ is either zero or some positive number.  Now sum over all the distinct $\Lambda_\alpha$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Is it because if I sum over all the measures of distinct $\Lambda_{\alpha}$ then I would get 0 since they are made up of points and the measure of a bunch of disjoint points is 0? But If I were to shift it in the right way I could get nonzero values... Sorry I am having a tough time with this problem.

Comment: I'm curious to know how you solved 1) and 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Henry hinted you, you should assume by contradiction that $m(\Lambda)=c > 0$.

Then you get $$\infty > m(S^1) = m(\bigcup_\alpha \Lambda_\alpha) = \sum_{\alpha} m(\Lambda_\alpha) = \sum_{\alpha} m(\Lambda) = \sum_{\alpha} c = \infty$$.

I would have loved commenting this as a comment instead but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> In this problem, we have countable many equivalence classes (ie. one
>   from each rational number)

That's incorrect. Each equivalence class has countably many members, and therefore there are *un*countably many equivalence classes. The rational numbers are all in the same class, and then there's a class with $\sqrt{2}-1$, and a class with $\pi-3$, and so on. A set of representatives, such as $\Lambda$, is therefore uncountable. If it *had* been countable, it would have been measurable, of measure $0$.

Comment: Oh thank you. I appreciate the clarification on that.